# Gorm - Updating model and appending to a slice

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm and have some questions as to how to update the model.  I'm getting an error trying to append &Comment to BlogPost struct.  Also trying to figure out how to persist the updated BlogPost to DB.

```
type BlogPost struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Content  string
    Comments []Comment
}

type ParentType int

const (
    PT_BlogPost ParentType = 1
    PT_Comment             = 2
)

type Comment struct {
    ID          uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ParentId    uint
    ParentType  ParentType
    Comment     string
    SubComments []Comment
}

func createComment(parentId uint, parentType ParentType) {
    switch parentType {
    case PT_BlogPost:
        var blogPost BlogPost
        // lookup blog post
        if err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&blogPost).Error; err != nil {
            return
        }
        // add comment as comment on blog post
        comment := &models.Comment{
            ParentId:    parentId,
            ParentType:  PT_BlogPost,
            Author:      "",
            Content:     "",
            SubComments: nil,
        }
        models.DB.Create(&comment)

        // TODO Error adding comment here
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, comment)

        // TODO How to update BlogPost with gorm
        models.DB.Model(&blogPost).Updates(blogPost)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gorm.Session attribute.

```
type BlogPost struct {
    ID       uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Content  string
    Comments []Comment
}

type ParentType int

const (
    PT_BlogPost ParentType = 1
    PT_Comment             = 2
)

type Comment struct {
    ID          uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    ParentId    uint
    ParentType  ParentType
    Comment     string
    SubComments []Comment
}

func createComment(parentId uint, parentType ParentType) {

    switch parentType {

    case PT_BlogPost:
        var blogPost BlogPost
        // lookup blog post
        if err := models.DB.Where("id = ?", parentId).First(&blogPost).Error; err != nil {
            return
        }

        // add comment as comment on blog post
        comment := &models.Comment{
            ParentId:    parentId,
            ParentType:  PT_BlogPost,
            Author:      "",
            Content:     "",
            SubComments: nil,
        }

        // TODO Error adding comment here
        blogPost.Comments = append(blogPost.Comments, comment)

        // TODO How to update BlogPost with gorm
        models.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Model(&blogPost).Updates(blogPost)

    }

}
```

`FullSaveAssociations: true` option works like upsert function. if you wanna update/create with relation, you can use this. also you should to use references and foreignkey for Comments model. `gorm:"foreignKey:parent_id;references:id"`.

if you want to get more information you can look below link;

https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Auto-Create-Update

Comment: Thanks, will try it.  How about the error with appending the comment pointer to the slice?

Comment: For some reason models.DB.Session is not available. What should I do? DB is defined as `var DB *gorm.DB`

Comment: `*gorm.DB` has Session attribute. are you sure? https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Session

Comment: Oh ok I was using an old version